# Bind to property in a nested static class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

I have the following construction:

```
public static class Constants {
  public static class Foo {
    public static string Bar {
      get {
        //Constants.Foo.Bar == "FooBar"
        return "FooBar";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to bind this to a button in a usercontrol.

```
<Button Content="{Binding Source={x:Static ns:Constants.Foo.Bar}}" />
```

(where ns points to the assembly and namespace where "Constants" is defined).
This results in two errors:

> - "Cannot find the type 'Constants.Foo'. Note that type names are case sensitive."
> - "Type 'ns:Constants.Foo' was not found."

I also tried:

```
<Button Content="{Binding Source={x:Static ns:Constants+Foo.Bar}}" />
```

This results in one error:

> - "Type 'ns:Constants+Foo' was not found."

Is is possible to bind to a static property in a static class in a static class? If yes, how?

Comment: Will did you also include the namespace before here `Constants+Foo.Bar` ? like `[namespace].Constants+Foo.Bar`

Comment: no, but I don't think it's needed (resharper removes the namespace). Testing 1, 2...: adding it doesn't help, same error ("was not found"), but now including the namespace.

Comment: It would work if you could change `public static class Constants` to `namespace Constants`. Is that an option?

Comment: It would require some refactoring, but that would be an option.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

this works for me

```
 <Button Content="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Constants+Foo.Bar}}" />
```

local is

```
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTestApp1"
```

Comment: You're right, but for some strange reason it does not work in XAML designer (VS2010).

Comment: Yes. Ouch. I didn't actually run the project, because the XAML design view gives errors. But it *does* work, you're right. I think I'll stick to the namespace solution, as suggested by Clemens, because a non-functioning designer is not acceptable during development.

Comment: just a hint the designer of VS2010 and Blend are not working the same way ;)

Comment: It works, but XAML designer write an error. I hate errors even if they don't hinder project to run :)